# What happens to an IDisposable object created in the middle of a statement that I cannot explicity call Dispose() on?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, garbage-collection, dispose

Say I'm working with Sharepoint (this applies to other object models as well) and in the middle of my statement, I call a method, in this case "OpenWeb()", which creates an IDisposable SPWeb object. Now, I cannot call Dispose() on the SPWeb object because I don't have the reference to it.  **So do I need to be concerned about this leaking memory?**

```
SPUser spUser = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current).OpenWeb().SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
```

I know that I could have broken up the statement into multiple lines and get the SPWeb reference to call Dispose:

```
SPWeb spWeb = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current).OpenWeb();
SPUser spUser = spWeb.SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
spWeb.Dispose();
```

Please keep in mind that my question is not about aesthetics, but more about what happens to the IDisposable object that I cannot explicitly call Dispose() on, since I don't have the reference.

Sorry about not being clear enough when I first asked the question.  I've since rephrased it.  Thanks for all the responses so far.

Comment: I can sympathize. There are many times when you call a method with IDisposable parameters, whose scopes begin and end with that method call.  What do you do if it takes 5 IDisposable parameters - nest using statements 5 levels deep?  Put 5 instantiations and 5 Disposes in a try..finally?  Ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"what happens to the IDisposable object that I cannot explicitly call Dispose() on?"

In general you can call Dispose (either implicitly with a using statement or explicitly)  on all disposable objects, however in the hypothetical scenario where you **can not**, it **depends** on the way the object was implemented.

In general, the .Net objects will follow pattern along [these lines](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid88562D7F1F6AB4C639B301D7C90A8B1E2924C1A4.aspx). The pattern is to define a finalizer that cleans stuff up in case dispose is not called and then have dispose suppress the finalizer. Which reduces memory load and gives the GC less work to do.

Amongst the many problems with calling Dispose from the finalizer, is that you are turning a single threaded problem into a multithreaded problem, the finalizer will run on a **different** thread which can expose some very subtle and hard to catch bugs. Also, it means you will be holding on to unmanaged resources for longer than expected (Eg. you open a file, forget to call close or dispose and next time you go to open it its locked)

Bottom line is, it is a **best practice** to dispose all disposable objects, otherwise you can introduce weird and complex bugs. With the caveat that some frameworks, like sharepoint, return shared instances of objects that should not be disposed according to the documentation.

I usually find the code much more readable when I dispose my objects with the "using" pattern. The problem with calling Dispose explicitly (object.Dispose()) is that it can be hard to trace where the object was allocated and it is very easy to forget. You can not forget to close the curly bracket of the using statement, the compiler will complain :)

**EDIT / GOTCHA**

According to [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) You should not call dispose on references to share point shared objects which are returned by GetContextSite. So, you should be extra careful here.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415313/what-happens-to-an-idisposable-object-created-in-the-middle-of-a-statement-that-i#456313) for a safe sharepoint pattern you should use.

> However, if you have a reference to a
>   shared resource, such as when the
>   object is provided by the
>   GetContextSite method in a Web Part,
>   do not use either method to close the
>   object. Using either method on a
>   shared resource causes an Access
>   Violation error to occur. In scenarios
>   where you have a reference to a shared
>   resource, instead let Windows
>   SharePoint Services or your portal
>   application manage the object.

Comment: Thanks! I like your response the most so far. I should have phrased my question the way quoted.  I've voted you up, but let me think about it some more.  In practice, I would have broken up the statement so I could explicitly call dispose. At work, we've had lots of Sharepoint out-of-memory issues.

Comment: Beware of non-SharePoint developers giving generic guidance - the rules are different in SharePoint because some SPSite/SPWeb objects are considered "owned" by the framework and should _not_ be disposed by custom code. dp's code below is correct.

Comment: I guess this question should be split .. I expanded my answer and linked back to yours.

Answer (score 4):

The following is more idiomatic and reads better as well:

```
using (SPWeb spWeb = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current).OpenWeb())
{
    SPUser spUser = spWeb.SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should explicitly (or implicitly via *using* statement) call Dispose method . Another reasons to split code in multiple lines are:

- readability
- it's easier to debug

Dispose method can be executed in finalizer, but it is safer to call it yourself.

Comment: Of course calling Dispose does not mean that the object will be GCed at that point, it only tells the GC that it's ready to be collected.

Comment: yep, but in context of this answer I think that author worries more about SPWeb's resources rather than class instance

Comment: Not all `IDisposable` objects have a finalizer; it is *common* to, but not mandated.

Comment: Marc, exactly! that's why I said that it is safer to call it manually

Comment: "it only tells the GC that it's ready to be collected" - this is wrong: calling Dispose does *not* tell the GC that an object is ready to be collected - it is ready to be collected when it's no longer reachable.  It *does* usually call SuppressFinalize but that's a different thing altogether.

Comment: That's wrong too.
Dispose only does exactly whats in it's method. No more. No less.  Dispose is used to release resources outside of .net managed memory in a controlled manner, ASAP. Eg. database connections, unmanaged memory.  The object will then get GC'd when the GC decides to.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest splitting the line and using Dispose. If an object implements IDisposable, you have to assume that it requires disposing and hence use it in a using block.

```
using (SPWeb spWeb = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current).OpenWeb())
{
    SpUser spUser = null;
    if (spWeb != null)
    {
        spUser = spWeb.SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
    }
}
```

By doing this you get to Dispose the object and also handle errors in your OpenWeb() call that is opening an external resource.

Answer (score 1):

Leaking memory?  No, you shouldn't be worried about it, assuming that the implementation of IDisposable adheres to the class library guidelines, as the next garbage collection should clean it up.

However, it does reveal an error in your code, as you aren't properly managing the lifetime of the implementations of IDisposable that you work with (I elaborate on this issue at http://www.caspershouse.com/post/A-Better-Implementation-Pattern-for-IDisposable.aspx).  Your second code block is a good first step, but you don't guarantee the calling of Dispose if the call to SiteUsers fails.

Your revised code would look like this:

```
// Get the site.
var contextSite = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current);

// Work with the web.
using (SPWeb web = contextSite.OpenWeb())
{
  // Get the user and work with it.
  SPUser spUser = web.SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
}
```

Comment: "next garbage collection should clean it up" ? Garbage collector wouldn't call Dispose method -> you'll get memory leak

Comment: You are taking the statement out of context.  I said assuming that it adheres to the class library guidelines.  If it does, then the finalizer will call the protected Dispose implementation which will free the resources.

Comment: sorry, I misread your post. anyway it is safer to not rely on this and call dispose manually

Comment: Again, assuming that the component adheres to the library guidelines it is safe in the sense that it will be disposed at *some* point, but it isn't deterministic.  Calling Dispose manually is only a good idea if it is in a finally block, or a using statement (which expands to a finally block).

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said by some so far: you must never dispose objects you dont create.
So in your example, you should *not* dispose either the SPWeb or SPSite object!

That will destroy the current SPRequest object. It might seem like it is still working, but if you for example add new web parts later, or try opening the tool pane for your web part, you will get all sorts of strange errors.

As it has already been said, it is a must to dispose instances of SPWeb and SPSite *that you create yourself* (new).

This can be done either with using() or with try/finally (which is the way a using() statement will show up in your MSIL code anyway). If you use try/finally it is best practice to check for null on your SPWeb/SPSite instance, and check for SPWeb first, as SPSite automatically will dispose your SPWeb.

Another important thing to remember is when looping SPWebCollections like AllWebs or Webs is to dispose your subwebs as you loop through them. If there are alot of sub webs, and you are running on 32-bit hardware with limited memory potential, you can fill up your memory with SPRequest objects very fast indeed. This will cause sluggish performance since it will cause your application pool to recycle regularily.

When that is said, it is also a good practice not to combine calls like you do in your code example. It is hard to read, and *if* you were working with an SPWeb that you should dispose, you couldnt! These kind of memory leaks are the hardest to spot, so dont do it ;-)

I can reccomend Roger Lamb's blog for details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla
Also some techincal details on Stefan Goßner’s blog:
http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/12/05/disposing-spweb-and-spsite-objects.aspx

hth
Anders

Answer (score 1):

Many answers here assume it's important only that Dispose is called eventually. When working with SPSite and SPWeb, however, you definitely want to call Dispose() as soon as you can. Determining *when* you should is often tricky, but there are many [good references](http://sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/When+to+Dispose+SharePoint+objects) available to help answer that question.

As to why this is the case, Stefan Goßner provides a great summary [here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/12/05/disposing-spweb-and-spsite-objects.aspx):

> Each SPWeb and SPSite object holds a
>   reference to an SPRequest object which
>   holds a reference to a SharePoint COM
>   object that is responsible to
>   communicate with the backend SQL
>   server.
>
> Disposing a SPWeb object will not
>   actually remove the SPWeb object from
>   memory (actually the .NET framework
>   does not allow to remove any object
>   from memory in a deterministic way)
>   but it will call a method of the SPWeb
>   object which causes the COM object to
>   close the connection to the SQL server
>   and to release its allocated memory.
>
> That means the connection to the
>   backend SQL server will remain open
>   from the moment the SPRequest object
>   has been created till the SPWeb object
>   is disposed.

The best practice for your code sample would look like this:

```
SPSite contextSite = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current);
using (SPWeb spWeb = contextSite.OpenWeb())
{
  SPUser spUser = spWeb.SiteUsers[@"foo\bar"];
  // Process spUser
}
// DO NOT use spUser
// DO NOT dispose site from HttpContext
```

Note that it is not safe to use SP objects like SPUser, SPList, etc. after their parent SPWeb has been disposed.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx *Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects*:

If the SPSite object is obtained from SPControl.GetContextSite, the calling application should NOT dispose of the object. Because the SPWeb and SPSite objects keep an internal list that is derived in this way, disposing of the object may cause the SharePoint object model to behave unpredictably.

Answer (score -1):

No one seems to have thrown this in yet:

If your object requires a disposer (i.e. takes hold of resources that must be released) then you should implement a finalizer that calls the disposer's method.

In the disposer you can add the line:

```
System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this)
```

Which will prevent finalization if you call the disposer.  That way you can use your object nicely if neccessary, but guarantee that it cleans up after itself via the finalizer, (which is the whole reason that C# does have a finalizer).

Comment: If an object with a finalizer holds a resource that's encapsulated in another object, when the first object's finalizer runs, the other object will most likely either (1) have already run its finalizer, (2) be already scheduled to run its finalizer, or (3) still be in use somewhere else.  In none of those cases should one try to do any cleanup on the other object.  The vast majority of the time, if one removes from a finalizer everything it shouldn't do, there will be nothing left (meaning the finalizer shouldn't exist at all).

Comment: If I have an object that attains some resource in native code, then that object MUST have a finalizer to guarantee that if the object falls out of scope and isn't disposed that the native resources are released.  This is why the .Net CLR will run finalizers for you when your application generates unhandled exceptions.  It's not error handling code, it's try and clean up after yourself code.

Comment: Indeed this is why FxCop has a rule that states that if an object has a disposer it is called to ensure that finalizers are suppressed where possible and resources are returned as quickly as possible.

Comment: Your original statement was "If your object requires a disposer... then it should implement a finalizer that calls the disposer's method.  That is only true if your object holds one or more resources that (1) can be usefully cleaned up in your object's finalizer, and (2) won't be cleaned up by some other finalizer (like those of objects encapsulating the resources).  Rarely will both conditions apply.  The vast majority of the time, a finalizer will do more harm than good.

Comment: An object which has a finalizer should not hold any references to any objects which are not needed for finalization.  If a complicated class has a piece which needs finalization, that piece should be separated off into its own smaller class; if object of the larger class holds the only reference to the smaller object, the smaller object will be finalized when the larger one would have been, but the garbage collector won't needlessly keep alive objects not needed for finalization.